# Vis JS Edge: display labels for the start and the end

Tags: javascript, vis.js-network, vis.js

I'm using VisJS to display a network map (i.e. links among routers and switches), so each VisJS' edge is a link between two devices for me.
Clicking on the edge, I'd like to display on both the extremities of the edge the two port of the devices, thanks to which they are connected.

For istance (in a very accurate graphical way!):

```
[8] ---------------- [15]
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you need is to use the `on` [method](http://visjs.org/docs/network/#methodGlobal) for the [`click`](http://visjs.org/docs/network/#event_click) event like this:

```
network.on('click',function(ev){
    if(ev.nodes.length != 0 || ev.edges.length != 1)
        return;
    var edge = ev.edges[0];
    // do what you need for that edge:
    // use edge.from and edge.to to get the corresponding nodes,
    // get the ports from wherever you have them stored,
    // add/show labels
});
```

Comment: In the meanwhile, I found something interesting at [this topic](https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/2104).
However trying to use it, I have all labels collapsed and overlaying.